# How those multiple complex requests can be turned into one ? (ActiveRecord, Arel)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, arel

Im trying to optimize some really greedy part of my code where i perform requests on really large tables. I'm calculating an average of a metric stored in a submodel for different timesteps and for this i'm looping and performing the requests for each timestep but im convinced this could be performed in a single request using Arel level.

Nevertheless im not super good with database stuff and could use some help or any input to know if thats even possible.

For a bit of context, here is a bit of explanation of the database:

I have a car model on which i collect data from the past, and perform simulations that generates simulated data for the future and store it in submodels.

here is what the database look like

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord 
  # each sim_step is corresponding 
  # to a point in time where 
  # simulations are performed
  has_many :sim_steps 
end

# t0: the point in time where the simulations start
# tf: duration of the simulations 
#    in seconds (simulations make 
#    calculations on the  
#    collected data, and generates 
#    sim_data from t0 to (t0 + 
#    tf.seconds))
class SimStep < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sims  
end

# state: state of the simulation 
#   (done / running)
# kind: the kind of simulation 
#   (different algorithms)
class Sim < ApplicationRecord 
  # sim_datas contain the metric 
  # for aggregation 
  has_many :sim_datas (that 
end
```

So here is how its done right now:

```
# Calculation of the average of :metric for each hour of the 12 past hours
# returns an Array of 12 values corresponding to the average of my metric for the 12 past hours
# [<avg for h-12 to h-11>, <avg for h-11 to h-10>, ... , <avg for h-1 to h-0>]
def previous_12_hours_avg
    @previous_12_hours_avg ||= (1..12).reverse_each.map do |offset|
      time = current_hour - offset.hour
      all_data_for_1_hour_since(time)
        &.average(:metric)
    end
end


def all_data_for_1_hour_since(time)
    best_sim_for_1_hour_since(time)  # returns the best simulation for time
      .sim_data 
      .where(
        'time': time..(time + 1.hour)
      )
end  

# retriving the best matching simulation in the past for a specific time frame
# this may look useful but i absolutely need this step
def best_simulation_for_1_hour_since(time)
    # this is scoped, and we're in the context of a model
    # here **sims** is corresponding to all of the simulations of a specific car model via a has_many through association (through sim_steps)
    sims
      .where(
        'sims.state': :done,
        'sims.kind': 'regular'
      )
      .order('sim_steps.t0': :desc)
      .where('sim_steps.t0 <= ?', time)
      .where("? - sim_steps.t0 < (sim.tf * '1 sec'::interval)", time + 1.hour).first
  end
```

This works as i want, but as the tables are really large this takes ages to execute and in some way i feel this is doable in a single request.

The super tricky parts that get me lost everytime im trying to figure out a solution are the fact i need to split my result in 12 different timesteps based on the current time, and that for each of those timestep i need to perform a subrequest to retrive the best simulation for that specific time and access its data.

I realize how tricky this is and i'm sorry in advance beacause i can't really be more specific about the code for confidentiality matters. I hope somehow this is clear enough and that somebody out there has a clue about it !

Thanks !

Comment: I feel that this is really going to stretch what can reasonably be done with Arel/ActiveRecord, and you might do better with a pure SQL approach.

Comment: If I understand correct the goal is an average metric grouped by hour for the last 12 hours. (Taking into account the already predefined filters in the question) If so then yes this almost certainly can be drastically simplified and all the heavy lifting put on the SQL server. If you confirm I will work on putting a solution together.

Comment: @DavidAldridge if you can write it in SQL. I bet I can write it in Arel.

Comment: @engineersmnky that would usually be of value if there were components to the required SQL that were useful elsewhere in the system, like in a scope for example. 

However, if the goal is an efficient data retrieval, then you have to start by knowing what the best SQL is anyway. After you've done that, you can then take a decision on the pros and cons of implementing it in Arel, or eg. as a view on which a read-only AR model is placed, or whether to leave it as SQL in a method, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and implication everyone. @engineersmnky Thats precisely it, and except for readability matters i don't really mind executing pure SQL. 

Those parts of the code are pretty technical anyways. Nevertheless if there is an Arel translation of the final SQL, my colleagues would appreciate i think. But it's not a big deal if not

Comment: On by the way we use PostrgreSQL in version 11.14, if that can be of any use

Comment: @engineersmnky Any chance you could think about this ?